# Q: How to pass multiple predicates to SQL in Python

Tags: python, sql, parameters

I am using ibm_db_dbi to connect to a DB2 database and need to pass multiple predicates to a SQL. I have some below example code that works but am having difficulty passing multiple predicates to the SQL. The goal is to pass the query to DB2 and then write the data back to either a list or dataframe in Python

Here is the query I want to pass to the database:

```
select someStuff
from tableA a join tableB b on a.key = b.key
where a.value = %s and a.date between %s and %s
```

I have a dataframe containing three columns (the value attribute, date1 and date 2) and a bunch of values in each of the columns. My plan was to pass the data in using a for loop and run the query as many times as I have rows in the dataframe then append each result back to a list object.

I am trying to build out to my goal from a modest, simple example query.  So far I have been able to run a query that contains a single parm but have had difficulty making it extensible to three. An issue is that I don't know how to reference the three separate 'columns' within the query object reference below.  Any help is appreciated

Below is my test query that works so far:

```
blahList = [-123,123]
dataDB2 = []

for item in blahList:
  aTestSQL = """
  select '%s' value from sysibm.sysdummy1
  """
  query = aTestSQL % (item)
  curDB2 = conDB2.cursor()
  curDB2.execute(query)
  dataDB2.append(curDB2.fetchone())
```

Comment: take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/blob/master/IBM_DB/ibm_db/ibm_db_dbi.py#L1337) you should not be string formatting your query but instead using parameter substitution, which the `Cursor` object allows

Comment: I see what you mean that the Cursor object allows for parameter substitution and think it is a better approach that what I came up with.  Unfortunately I could not get parameter substitution working with the cursor. If you would be willing to take a look at the solution I posted and show me an example of cursor parameter substitution that does the same thing, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: can you share a code snippet of how you tried parameter substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I came up with, maybe it will help the next person:

```
blahlist = [(-1990963710,'ralph'), (3912019,'wreckit')]
dataDB2 = []

for idx, val in enumerate(blahlist):
  number = val[0]
  name = val[1]

  aTestSQL = """
  select %d NUMBER, '%s' NAME from sysibm.sysdummy1
  """
  query = aTestSQL % (number,name)
  curDB2 = conDB2.cursor()
  curDB2.execute(query)
  dataDB2.append(curDB2.fetchall())
```